# How to delete/free a string literal?

Tags: c++, memory, c++17, string-literals

I have a `std::vector<const char*>` which I populate by `.push_back("something")`. How to delete contents not including `std::string`'s header? `delete` segfaults, and `std::free` needs `void*` and it "cannot initialize [..] with an lvalue of type 'const char *'".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You don't delete string literals. If you're only pushing literals, you cannot delete them.

Comment: And if you're pushing in string literals along with dynamically allocated `char` arrays you do need to `delete`, you're going to find that it's next-to-impossible to tell them apart. May I recommend using `std::string` end-to-end in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals have static storage duration. You may not delete them using the operator delete. String literals will be alive until the program ends,

You may delete what was created using the operator new.

You can just erase all or selected elements of the vector or clear it entirely.

Answer (score 9):

You may `delete` only what you `new`. You didn't use `new` to create the string literals, so using `delete` on them will result in undefined behaviour. Don't do that.  Similarly, you may `free` only what you `malloc` (plus a few related functions that `malloc` internally).

String literals have static storage duration. That means that their storage is deallocated automatically at the end of the program without your intervention.

You can erase the pointers from the vector using the `erase` member function.

Answer (score 1):

String literals like `"something"` are stored in a read-only segment of the executable. You can not `delete` them. And also, modifying them is undefined behavior.

Comment: Location in the executable file (something not defined by C++) isn't important here. It's purely a matter of only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: @user4581301 Right. However, sometimes it's good to talk a bit about implementation details too.